# How to use funnel3d of highcharts in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, highcharts

I am trying to use funnel3d in my React project. I have imported the following modules and tried to display the sample chart from highcharts official docs https://www.highcharts.com/demo/funnel3d

```
`import * as Highcharts from "highcharts";
 import HighchartsReact from "highcharts-react-official";
 import highcharts3d from "highcharts/highcharts-3d";
 import cylinder from "highcharts/modules/cylinder";
 import Funnel from "highcharts/modules/funnel3d.js";
 import HC_exporting from "highcharts/modules/exporting";
 cylinder(Highcharts);
 Funnel(Highcharts);
 highcharts3d(Highcharts);
 HC_exporting(Highcharts);



let funnelOptions = {
chart: {
    type: 'funnel3d',
    options3d: {
        enabled: true,
        alpha: 10,
        depth: 50,
        viewDistance: 50
    }
},
title: {
    text: 'Highcharts Funnel3D Chart'
},
plotOptions: {
    series: {
        dataLabels: {
            enabled: true,
            format: '<b>{point.name}</b> ({point.y:,.0f})',
            allowOverlap: true,
            y: 10
        },
        neckWidth: '30%',
        neckHeight: '25%',
        width: '80%',
        height: '80%'
    }
},
series: [{
    name: 'Unique users',
    data: [
        ['Website visits', 15654],
        ['Downloads', 4064],
        ['Requested price list', 1987],
        ['Invoice sent', 976],
        ['Finalized', 846]
    ]
}]}
render() {
<HighchartsReact highcharts={Highcharts} options={funnelOptions} />
}
`
```

It is giving me an error "Cannot read property 'perspective' of undefined perspective' of undefined at eval (VM399114 cylinder.js:13) at h (VM399114 cylinder.js:11) at eval (VM399114 cylinder.js:13) at eval (VM399112 PhaseFunnelChart.jsx:47)".

Do I need to import any other module before using it? PhaseFunnelChart.jsx is the name of the component. Is there any mistake in importing cylinder module?

Comment: I don't see where any `perspective` is referenced in the provided code snippet. Is this a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)? Can you add the error message and stacktrace to your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably you forgot to add a highcharts-3d dependency in your project. I've prepared a working demo with your code.

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-forked-pc9ez?file=/demo.jsx

API references: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-and-series-types/funnel-3d#setting-up